# not able to remove category in select2

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-select2

I am using `select2` in angular custom modal pop up. I can add multiple category as well as I can I can remove it when I click cancel symbol but when I remove category from that list, I am not able to remove last two category. I do not know the reason. Can anybody help me? my HTML code like below

```
<select select2 id='category'  data-close-on-select="false" ng-model="text.category" select-selection="text.category" class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple" select-options="child in category_list">
    <option value="">-- Select Category --</option>
</select>
```

Comment: the javascript?

Comment: i am using jquery select2 in angular

Comment: thanks didn't see the tags, so where is the javascript?

Comment: Actually i included  select2.js(jquery plugin file whic downloaded from https://select2.github.io) in html page

Comment: its working but i could not remove last 2 category from my list

Comment: The javascript from where `category_list` or `category` is coming

Comment: its from database.i called api to get category_list from db